# How to extract certain strings from hyperlink and create a folder with same string in bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, wget

I have a text file(web.txt) containing a long list of urls with this pattern

```
http://www.example.com/ab1.htm
http://www.example.com/ab2.htm
http://www.example.com/bc1.htm
http://www.example.com/qw3.htm
.
.
http://www.example.com/xc15.htm
```

I want to fetch the URL list and then extract the webpage last string without .htm in the url (ab1,ab2,bc1..xc15) as variable and then create a new folder with that name. Then using wget I want to download that webpage to the newly created folder.

```
#!/bin/bash
NAMES=`cat web.txt` #urls from web.txt file
for NAME in $NAMES; do
   echo "$NAME"
   NEWNAME=#string from url
   mkdir -p /home/$NEWNAME
   wget $NAME
done
```

I was able to fetch the URLS from my web.txt file but I have these two problems

1. How to extract the string from url?
2. How to for loop and download the webpage to the newly created folder?

Comment: Hmm...  Good question, though it might be better on http://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you haven't re-read `man bash` enough times. This is simply:

```
BASEDIR="$HOME"
for myurl in $( cat web.txt ) ; do
    # erase everything "*" up to the last "/"
    mydir="${myurl##*/}"
    # erase the trailing "%"  ".htm"
    mydir=${mydir%.htm}
    mkdir -p $BASEDIR/$mydir
    # run the wget in a subshell, in the new directory
    (cd $BASEDIR/$mydir;wget "$myurl")
done
```

IMHO, a good set of options to use with `wget` (read `man wget` to see if they're good for you, too) is `--no-parent --relative --page-requisites --convert-links -nv -t 3 --waitretry=6 --random-wait`, but YMMV.

Answer (score 4):

```
while read url; do
    newname="$(basename "$url" .htm)"
    mkdir -p "/home/$newname"
    wget -O "/home/$newname/$newname.htm" "$url"
done < web.txt
```